# java nio: if read returns -1 does it mean client has closed connection?

Tags: java, nio

I have a question with reference to this tutorial

http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/

In the read method of the server, if read returns -1 then does it always mean client has closed connection??

I modified the example client to sleep for long time after sending the message I see that the selector.select() does not block and keeps selecting the channel as readable even if client is not sending anything and server reads method reads and returns -1, and thus closes the channel, but the client has not disconnected.

I do not understand this behavior. Can some one help me understand?

I am trying to modify the server so that the server does not disconnect with client even if client is not sending anything and so it must block at selector.select().

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the read method of the server if
>   read returns -1 then does it always
>   mean client has closed connection?

Yes. Always.

> server reads method reads and returns -1 , and thus closes the channel , but the client has not disconnected.

Yes it has. That's what it means. The client has closed the connection.

Comment: I love this. Two unexplained downvotes and it is also marked as correct, which it is.

Answer (score 3):

The API should work as described. Read will return -1 when the socket connection is closed. This is not the same as "end of message". A connection can be closed by a time-out and I note that you said you had the client wait for "a long time".

I also note that you are working from a specific tutorial. The client code in that tutorial specifically closes the connection after receiving a response and opens a new one for every send. You would have to make large changes to the client code design to stop this.

When I run the nio server from that tutorial with a client that does not close the connection, the behaviour is as the API describes - the server thread waits in Selector.select() whilst the client sleeps between sending messages.

My answer is hence that you are probably using a client that is closing connections, and if not the "long time" you are waiting could cause the network to close the connections for you. Given the behaviour you describe I am pretty sure it is the former.

Answer (score 0):

I guess - but I am not really sure, cause I didn't read it completely - you fail in the distinction between Port-connection and Socket-connection. To my understanding the connection is opened via a socket on a specific port. The socket could be closed resp. received the end of the message which was sent - but the connection could still remain.

To my understanding -1 indicates the end of the messages sent via the socket-connection. There is no clear indicator which tells you directly the connection is closed.... You have to invent it by yourself. (My 2cents of understanding.)

Comment: This answer makes very little sense. There is no such thing as a port-connection as opposed to a socket-connection. There are only connections. If the peer closed the connection you get -1. If you closed it yourself you get a SocketClosedException. There is no third possibility. You can't close a port or a connection, you can only close a socket, which is your endpoint to a connection.

Comment: You can establish the connection e.g. on port 3500. The server could make 3 socket-connection on port 3500. If one of the 3 socket-connection are closed, you get for the one closed, a -1, but the other 2 connection remain open (on port 3500).

Comment: [EDIT was not possible, therefore the rest] What you, EJP, write is only valid if you have ONE-socket to port connection and not multiple socket-connections over one port. So, receiving -1 does NOT necessarily mean, that the 'client disconnected from the server' but would mean 'ONE socket-connection from ONE client is closed'. i.e. -1 could still mean, that another connection remains vivid.

Comment: @LeO: Your terminology is so inexact it is difficult to tell what exactly you are talking about. (1) There is no such thing as a 'socket-connection' or 'over one port'. There are (i) ports, (ii) connections, and (iii) sockets. (2) If the peer closes the connection, you read -1 on it. If you read -1 on a connection, the peer has closed it. (3) In the situation you now describe, the phrase 'client has disconnected from the server' has no meaning. I didn't use it. You did. In that situation, the connection on which you read -1 has been closed, the others remain open.

Comment: @EJP: I agree with (2). I do NOT understand your blaming with (3) cause you are arguing about my words and what *you* did NOT use. Fine. But the original poster asked exactly that way 'the read method of the server, if read returns -1 then does it always mean client has closed connection?' (Answer: NO, cause client could have opened other sockets!) So, why blame me, when I tried to answer the original question? AND to my understanding, the question was reg. SERVER and not client. Feel free to stuck to my words or to client-point-of-view. I only tried to provide an answer to what was asked.

Comment: @Leo You said 'The socket could be closed resp. received the end of the message which was sent - but the connection could still remain.' This is simply untrue. That connection is closed. Period. Other connections may or may not exist, and reading them may or may not return -1. It's irrevelant. And the concept of 'the client disconnecting from the server' over a number of connections still doesn't have any actual meaning. And my downvote concerns the accuracy of your answer, not your intention. That's how SO works.